# overriding a constraint in AMPL

Tags: constraints, overriding, ampl

I am wondering how we can override a constraint in AMPL. in a very basic example :

```
var x >= 0  ;
var y  >= 0;

minimize cost : x^2 + y^4;

subject to constraint1 : x+2*y >= 100;

subject to constraint1 : x+2*y <= 10;

---------------------------------

"constraint1 is already defined"
```

AMPL uses the first "constraint1" as its constraint and ignores the second one , is there any way that AMPL uses the last "constraint1" ?

Comment: use a different name for the second constraint

Comment: I don't want to use 2 constraints , I just want to override the previous constraint with new one.

Comment: if you have data and run files then you can probably write the constraints as x+2*y>=low_lim and x+2*y<=up_lim, make low_lim=100 and up_lim=999999 in the data file, and script the run file to make low_lim=0 and up_lim=10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to override constraints with the same variable name.

It is possible to toggle between constraints that are assigned to the same name via conditional logic (if statements come to mind), but they cannot be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned from @Everyone_Else you can use an if statement.

In the AMPL book in Chapter 13, there are some examples of how to use it, in particular, subchapter:

- 13.4 Testing a condition: the if-then-else statement.

https://ampl.com/resources/the-ampl-book/chapter-downloads/

Your case would look like this:

```
if -->condition<--
 subject to constraint1 : x+2*y >= 100;
else
 subject to constraint1 x+2*y <= 10;
```